# Clarification on conversations about resistances

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a query as a result of reading your questions and answers regarding resistances and armour for Diablo 3.

When you state (for example) 700 resistance, do you mean 700 total resistance or 700 resistance for each different resistance?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're asking?  This doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Reading *whose* file, where?

Answer (score 5):

When someone says "I have 700 to all resistances", he/she means that each of his/her resistances has a value of 700, not that the sum of them is 700.

Answer (score 1):

When somebody is discussing resistances and states (for example) "700 to all resistances" means each resistance has 700 in it.

The possible exception to this is Monks using the 'One With Everything' passive, which increases your resistance to all elements to equal your highest elemental resistance.